# switch case in JQ while creating new object

Tags: jq

I would like to use IF THEN in my JQ query while creating a new object but I'm getting an error

```
.customer | {"company": .companyName, "email": .email, "phone": .phone,
             "type": if .customerType.name == "A" then "SOHO" else "Other" end
            }
```

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected if (Unix shell quoting issues?) at
> , line 2:
> "type": if .customerType.name == "A" then "SOHO" else "Other" end                      jq: 1 compile error exit status 3

Comment: Use parens: `"type": (if … end)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parenthesize the value expression:

```
.customer | {
  "company": .companyName,
  email,
  phone,
  "type": (if .customerType.name == "A" then "SOHO" else "Other" end)
}
```

Comment: You meant using parentheses, not a quote - right?

Comment: @g_m whoops, yes, of course. My bad. Post is fixed :)